# How to call matlab self defined function with c++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, function, interactive

If I define the `add(a,b)` function in matlab file `add.m`,how can I call it from c++ code?
one simple example like this:
add.m:

```
function y=add(a,b)
y=a+b;
end
```

c++ code:

```
int main(){
// call add(a,b) ?
}
```

Acturally, I need to use more compilicate matlab function,like `cp2tform()` and `imtransform()` in my cpp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate c code from matlab [via this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/14/generating-c-code-from-your-matlab-algorithms/). And call from your main function.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to convert `cf2tform` function which can't be tranfrom by `matlab coder`.

Comment: I don't know what is that method and couldn't find it online. But I really doubt that you can call any .m file from c++. Alternatively, I would look for similar functions in OpenCV. For example, http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine might contain a similar function as `imtransform`.

Comment: You're so nice,thanks again. But I need to use `similarity transform` in matlab , in detail , tranform one image with 5 points(src points) to another one template image(dst points), which method is not a simple` affine transform` in opencv. And another confusion is that the `estimateRigidTransform`(opencv api) can't accept 5 points transform, but sometime's can't produce `transform matrix` (T_mat = 0).

Answer (score 1):

You can call the MATLAB engine from C/C++ programs. See e.g. the [external interfaces reference R2016b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/apiext.pdf) or the [online documentation on the MATLAB Engine](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html). When using the Matlab engine in a C/C++ code, you would only need to call `engEvalString(MyEngine,"add(a,b)");` after passing `a` and `b` to Matlab with the `engPutVariable` command.